# Update docvariable or docproperty in Word online

Tags: ms-word, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Is ther a way to update docvariable or docproperty of a Word document when opening in the Word online by the microsoft graph API or another API.

I do this in Word for desktop using C# code, but I need to do this in Word online too.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done in Word on-line. If you had an Office JS add-in you might be able to change document properties (but no DocProperty fields that reflect those values). The Word JS APIs do not access the Document Variables, however.

But you should be able to do it on the *closed* file (before it's opened in Word on-line, for example) by leveraging the Word Open XML file format. There are numerous libraries to work with it. Microsoft's is the Open XML SDK (free, as a .NET Framework / Visual Studio extension) which can access all content of Office files (except VBA binaries).

Comment: It's what I already imagined but wanted to confirm.

Thanks Cindy